# Phrase for taking ones own medicine

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

Is there a word or phrase that describes someone who cannot take what they verbally dish out or criticise.

Comment: There is, of course, the phrase "a dose of his own medicine" for someone who is ironically subjected to the same ills he has previously heaped on others.

Comment: Your question seems good to me, but it is not clear. How would you use the phrase in a sentence? Please edit your question to add a sample sentence that has a blank ( __ ) in the place where the word or phrase would occur.

Comment: 'Own medicine' is too worn a phrase. It has lost its effect, at least on this person I have in mind. I was looking for something stronger. She is abusive and has low tolerance, readily and harshly criticising over the smallest of things - in most cases her anger is unjustified.

Answer (score 1):

In lieu of a more specific term, "hypocrite" might be a solution.

*"a person who claims or pretends to have certain beliefs about what is right but who behaves in a way that disagrees with those beliefs"* (Merriam Webster)

For this to work, however, it would need to be clear that the person who "dishes it out" implicitly or explicity claims that accepting criticsm is an essential quality; only then would there be a conflict between this indvidual's claimed beliefs and behavior.

Comment: Can be but looking for a sub-set of this which has less to with beliefs than just day to day behaviour and criticisms

Comment: Perhaps one might humorously call them an *expositor*, provided that the candidate at least claims to offer constructive advice. Of course, this lacks the flavor of abusiveness; furthermore, criticising others is a very specific form of 'exposition' which this suggestion does not account for.

Answer (score 1):

***Thin-skinned***, defined by [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thin%E2%80%93skinned) as

> easily bothered by criticism or insults: very sensitive

Example: My friend is very thin-skinned; if I even imply that she is not perfect, she gets huffy.  But she doesn't hesitate to tell what she thinks I am doing wrong!

(I think anyone who puts up with this is an enabler.)

Unless the person the OP describes is actually abusive, *thin-skinned* is a good descriptor.  But if the person is abusive, *thin-skinned* doesn't work. ***Disturbed*** is the kindest word I can think of in that case, as defined [here](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=disturbed+meaning)

> suffering or resulting from emotional and mental problems

Comment: Can be but something then that combines it with disturbed